Disable search engine popup with chromedriver option does not work
I am using chromedriver with PowerShell to automate chrome.
I have trouble with the recent search-engine selection popup.
The proposed solution ist to add the option
--disable-search-engine-choice-screen

but that does not work for me. I am already adding various options, and they do work as expected, so the code works in general.
Code snippet:
  $ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
    $ChromeOptions.AddArguments(@(
        "--disable-extensions",
        "--disable-notifications",
        "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
        "--disable-search-engine-choice-screen"
    ))
    $ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", $false)
    $ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", $false)

But this last option does not. It has no effect, the popup still appears every time the script starts chrome.
Anyone has an idea why this is the case?

I am experiencing the same issue with selenium-webdriver under javascript (node). @Rob did you manage to get it working?

Unfortunately , not yet. Its really odd though, because it seems to be an accepted and therefore seemingly working solution for some people.
I added a bug here: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/357068286 , maybe vote it up.

Just did, thanks. I don't quite like the proposed workaround of searching and setting a default search engine, it's like programming around broken behavior. Will try it out though.

did not work for me, or rather I could not get it to work with PowerShell

you need to add the option "--disable-search-engine-choice-screen"
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")

# Now initialize the Chrome driver with these options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


Did you read the question at all, or just the title? :)

What is the error code?

There is no error code. The settings simply has no effect what so ever. The popup still appears.

Are you use this module to install chrome driver, or it's fix  ?webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

I am not sure what you are asking. I am using Powershell, and launching and using chromedriver works. The other options listed above work. Just this option "--disable-search-engine-choice-screen" does not.
